# Start a service in the linux machine in the static mode

Tags: linux

I want to start the tmp.mount service in the static mode. To make this I have removed the [Install] portion in the unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tmp.mount`
But still I get the status as enabled-runtime instead of static.
What is the issue here ?

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl is-enabled tmp.mount
enabled-runtime
```